# jQuery UI: Reject draggable in partially overlaid droppable?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-droppable

I have a large jQuery UI `droppable` that is overlaid by some other elements. When I hover a `draggable` over the elements that actually obscure the `droppable`, the `droppable` still receives the `ui-state-hover` class. How can we avoid that?

It seems there is no chance to implement the `accept` function of the `droppable` s.t. it decides by the cursor coordinates, at least I can't get it to work: If it returns `false` once, it won't be queried again until the cursor re-enters the obscured `droppable`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure there is a native way of doing it. But you can make the overlay elements `droppable` as well and on `over` and `out` disable and enable the 'real' `droppable`. Like this for example:

```js
$('#droppable').droppable({
    accept: '#draggable:not(.overObscure)',
    greedy: true,
    overlay: 'ha',
    drop: function (e, ui) {
        console.log(this)
    }
});

$('#overlay').droppable({
    accept: '#draggable',
    over: function (e, ui) {
        ui.draggable.addClass('overObscure');
    },
    out: function (e, ui) {
        ui.draggable.removeClass('overObscure');
    }
});


$('#draggable').draggable();
```

```css
#droppable {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #ddd;
}
#overlay {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background-color: blue;
}
#draggable {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.2.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<div id="droppable"></div>
<div id="overlay"></div>
<div id="draggable"></div>
```

You could also add the behavior to droppable so it's easier to call. Like this for example:

```js
$.widget("ui.droppable", $.ui.droppable, {
    _create: function () {
        var that = this;
        this._super();
        $(this.options.overlay).droppable({
            accept: this.options.accept,
            over: function (e, ui) {
                that.options.disabled = true;
            },
            out: function (e, ui) {
                that.options.disabled = false;
            }
        });
    }
})

$('#droppable').droppable({
    accept: '#draggable',
    greedy: true,
    overlay: '#overlay',
    drop: function (e, ui) {
        console.log('dropped')
    }
});

$('#draggable').draggable();
```

```css
#droppable {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #ddd;
}
#overlay {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background-color: blue;
}
#draggable {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.2.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<div id="droppable"></div>
<div id="overlay"></div>
<div id="draggable"></div>
```